# Strange results using android PHP API Library

Tags: php, android, api, google-play

Using a [PHP implementation of the java android market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api-php/) I'm attempting to display the top 10 most popular applications.

Using the code below:

```
<?php
include("local.php");
include("../proto/protocolbuffers.inc.php");
include("../proto/market.proto.php");
include("../Market/MarketSession.php");

$session = new MarketSession();
$session->login(GOOGLE_EMAIL, GOOGLE_PASSWD);
$session->setAndroidId(ANDROID_DEVICEID);

$ar = new AppsRequest();
$ar->setOrderType(AppsRequest_OrderType::POPULAR);
$ar->setStartIndex(0);
$ar->setEntriesCount(10);
//free or paid
//$ar->setViewType(AppsRequest_ViewType::ALL);
//arcade etc
//$ar->setCategoryId("ARCADE");


$reqGroup = new Request_RequestGroup();
$reqGroup->setAppsRequest($ar);

$response = $session->execute($reqGroup);

$groups = $response->getResponsegroupArray();
foreach ($groups as $rg) {
    $appsResponse = $rg->getAppsResponse();
    $apps = $appsResponse->getAppArray();
    foreach ($apps as $app) {
          echo $app->getTitle()."<br/>";

    }
}
```

But the results I'm getting aren't exactly what I expected:

```
Brightest Flashlight Freeâ„¢
LauncherPro
Seesmic (Facebook, Twitter)
Android Assistant(18 features)
Pho.to Lab
US Yellow Pages
Sudoku Free
Color Flashlight
ElectroDroid
Scanner Radio
```

I expected the list of top 10 apps to contain Gmail, Facebook, Youtube etc

Anyone know why this could be happening? Any alternative APIs we could use? Any other way we can acheive this?

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. Are you sure one of the filters like "ANDROID_DEVICEID" isn't limiting results?

Comment: ANDROID_DEVICEID, GOOGLE_EMAIL and GOOGLE_PASSWD fields are all required to get anything at all back from the API.

Comment: I expected the list of top 10 apps to contain Gmail, Facebook, Youtube etc

Comment: The author of `Brightest Flashlight Freeâ„¢` must be a millionaire!

Comment: This way is not effective. It is not an official API and it's developers can change or update several time, therefore you will need change your code or approach several time. I created an app with this unofficial API, first time it worked well, then after 1 month crashed, and again became working, then crashed again. And this API can retrieve information not about all applications on the Market. I think that the developers have their own database and they update it when they want. I decided to do not use this API.

Comment: @Daryn Could you share what API you did use?